# NodeJS: Rotating JPEG with GM not working

Tags: node.js, image, jpeg, graphicsmagick

I'm writing an API endpoint to accept images and send them to my S3 server.  Before that, however, it has to orient the images correctly so that not display wrong when in image tags.  Since JPEGs use exif data to determine image rotation and the img tag does not refer to the exif data for orientation information, my images appear sideways on my website, but right side up on other platforms. Here is my code for rotating the image:

```
if (file.mimetype == 'image/jpeg'){
    var exifData = Parser.create(uploadedFile).parse();

    if (exifData.tags.Orientation == 6 || exifData.tags.Orientation == 8){
        var degrees = exifData.tags.Orientation == 6 ? 90 : 270;

        gm(file.path).rotate('black', degrees).write(file.path, function(err){
            if (err)
                return cb1(err);

            finish();
        });
    }else
        finish();
}else
    finish();
```

`finish()` is the function that sends the file off to S3.  Why is it that my image is not rotating?  I have it set to overwrite the existing file on rotate.  There are no errors being returned, as the entire call would fail.

Comment: The rotate function is successfully called, and the image is indeed rotated by 90 degrees.

Comment: Have you updated or removed the exif data from your rotated image?  gm won't update it for you, and won't remove it by default.